# htaccess for multilingual site

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i want the htaccess code which would allow just letters and numbers from all languages to be displayed properly.

the url stucture is:

http://example.com/word-{here is the first letter of the the keyword}/{here is the keyword it self}/

I am looking at

Rewriterule ^word-[a-z0-9]/[a-z0-9]+/ index.php?key=$1&keyword=$2 [L]

I want one where if the keyword is not english it still works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriterule ^word-[a-z0-9]/[a-z0-9]+/ index.php?key=$1&keyword=$2 [L] should be fine. but i would suggest using php for url rewriting.

Comment: "letters and numbers from all languages" - how is this going to work for `word-š/švestka/`? (hint: it won't match)

Answer (score 1):

Would "match anything" help?

```
Rewriterule ^word-(.|(%[a-z0-9A-Z]{1,2})+)/([^/]+)/ index.php?key=$2&keyword=$3 [L]
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it would match anything. whats is the difference in (.*) and ([6/]+). For example see this url http://domainsoutlook.com/word-%E0%A4%87/%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0/

Comment: @user381595: hmm, so you're getting the result urlencoded? Edited.